# Spritekit-how to flip a sprite horizontally when exposed to gravity

Tags: ios, swift

Im trying to build an app where  i want  the sprite image to flip to the right when gravity pulls it to the right.

The original sprite image is facing in the left direction and moves to the left when touched (anywhere on screen) through touches began.

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to rotate it 90 degrees then try this:

```
sprite.zRotation =  M_PI/2.0f
```

So I'm thinking 180 degrees would be this:

```
sprite.zRotation = M_PI
```

Edit:

So if you want to invert the image try:

```
sprite.xScale = -1.0;
```

But if your node has any child nodes it will invert those as well.

Comment: I want to invert the image horzontally - rotating it makes the image upside down.